# How to access System colour list in windows form c#

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am using `windows form`.

As shown in the screenshot

[image: screenshot]

To change `button` `backColour` using code you do this:

```
 button_1.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Using this code I can only select any colour from the `Web` list but I can not find a colour which is listed in the `System` section. For Example I can not find the "InactiveCaptionText" colour programmatically.

Anyone knows how to change `button` `backColour` to a colour from the `System` list using code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use the [`System.Drawing.SystemColors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors(v=vs.110).aspx), you might find there the `InactiveCaptionText` you're searching for.

Comment: In case the OP switches to WPF or Core this can be found under `System.Drawing.KnownColor`

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [SystemColors.InactiveCaptionText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors.inactivecaptiontext(v=vs.110).aspx) Property which returns a [Color](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color(v=vs.110).aspx) structure that is the color of the text in an inactive window's title bar.and use as below:

```
using System.Drawing;
//Method call
button_1.BackColor = SystemColors.InactiveCaptionText;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use RGB color...or hex function and create your own color.

```
private Color RgbExample()
{
    // Create a green color using the FromRgb static method.
    Color myRgbColor = new Color();
    myRgbColor = Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0);
    return myRgbColor;
}
To get all colors 

List<System.Windows.Media.Color> listOfMediaColours = new List<System.Windows.Media.Color>();
foreach(KnownColor color in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)))
{
    System.Drawing.Color col = System.Drawing.Color.FromKnownColor(color);
    listOfMediaColours.Add(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(col.A, col.R, col.G, col.B));
}
```

Hex way to get color

```
using System.Windows.Media;
```

Color color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFDFD991");

Comment: Legit answer, for sure... but... RGB, really? Instead of accessing a prop? Sounds weird :s

Comment: Believe rgb it is also good way. RGB could be easily transformed to hex if it necessary, so by the end there is no difference between RGB or HEX or any other method which you will choice. It is up to you.

Comment: As long as you can master it, it's good enough! I preffer accessing a property with "all ready to be used" :P